# Set up a single ip for egress / ingress traffic on a docker swarm

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm with 3 vms:

- node1: 192.168.10.1
- node2: 192.168.10.2
- node3: 192.168.10.3

Is it possible to have an ip **192.168.10.4** for both ingress and egress traffic.

I know one way of doing the ingress part is with keepalived.

Comment: Afaik, Docker swarm doesn't provide such feature and that's why you get no answer to this question. Some CNI in Kubernetes provide such feature but even there it's uncommon. Example for an open-source one that is not production ready:  https://github.com/nirmata/kube-static-egress-ip#how-it-works . You'd probably have to implement somehow something similar in Docker (which uses "CNM" rather than "CNI" ).